# Get local time zone on Android without SIM

Tags: android, time, timezone

For my app functionality, I need to have a correct time set on a device. For example, I use AlarmManager to do some action at 7:00 AM. It's a tablet with Wi-Fi connection. Network-provided time works well, time & date can be set automatically over Wi-Fi, but time zone not. The device may appear in different time zones. How to solve this problem? Do I need to ask the user to set the proper time zone on the first launch of the app or it can be synced another way?

Comment: Can't you just always convert all times to UTC?